# jquery-ui.min.js throwing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined jquery-ui.min.js:5

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dropdown.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/placeholders.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.multiple.select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have use this jquery when i load page in chrome i am getting this error-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined jquery-ui.min.js:5
e.fn.position jquery-ui.min.js:5
e.uiBackCompat.e.fn.position jquery-ui.min.js:5
(anonymous function)
```

ie shows javascript error:

> return
>   w.nodeType===9?(l=g.width(),d=g.height(),v={top:0,left:0}):e.isWindow(w)?(l=g.width(),d=g.height(),v={top:g.scrollTop(),left:g.scrollLeft()}):w.preventDefault?(t.at="left top",l=d=0,v={top:w.pageY,left:w.pageX}):(l=g.outerWidth(),d=g.outerHeight(),v=g.offset()),m=e.extend({},v),e.each(["my","at"],function(){var
>   e=(t[this]||"").split("
>   "),n,r;e.length===1&&(e=o.test(e[0])?e.concat(["center"]):u.test(e[0])?["center"].concat(e):["center","center"]),e[0]=o.test(e[0])?e[0]:"center",e[1]=u.test(e[1])?e[1]:"center",n=a.exec(e[0]),r=a.exec(e[1]),S[this]=[n?n[0]:0,r?r[0]:0],t[this]=[f.exec(e[0])[0],f.exec(e[1])[0]]}),E.length===1&&(E[1]=E[0]),t.at[0]==="right"?m.left+=l:t.at[0]==="center"&&(m.left+=l/2),t.at[1]==="bottom"?m.top+=d:t.at[1]==="center"&&(m.top+=d/2),n=h(S.at,l,d),m.left+=n[0],m.top+=n[1],this.each(function(){var o,u,a=e(this),f=a.outerWidth(),c=a.outerHeight(),w=p(this,"marginLeft"),x=p(this,"marginTop"),T=f+w+p(this,"marginRight")+b.width,N=c+x+p(this,"marginBottom")+b.height,C=e.extend({},m),k=h(S.my,a.outerWidth(),a.outerHeight());t.my[0]==="right"?C.left-=f:t.my[0]==="center"&&(C.left-=f/2),t.my[1]==="bottom"?C.top-=c:t.my[1]==="center"&&(C.top-=c/2),C.left+=k[0],C.top+=k[1],e.support.offsetFractions||(C.left=s(C.left),C.top=s(C.top)),o={marginLeft:w,marginTop:x},e.each(["left","top"],function(r,i){e.ui.position[E[r]]&&e.ui.position[E[r]]i}),e.fn.bgiframe&&a.bgiframe(),t.using&&(u=function(e){var
>   n=v.left-C.left,s=n+l-f,o=v.top-C.top,u=o+d-c,h={target:{element:g,left:v.left,top:v.top,width:l,height:d},element:{element:a,left:C.left,top:C.top,width:f,height:c},horizontal:s<0?"left":n>0?"right":"center",vertical:u<0?"top":o>0?"bottom":"middle"};lr(i(o),i(u))?h.important="horizontal":h.important="vertical",t.using.call(this,e,h)}),a.offset(e.extend(C,{using:u}))})},e.ui.position={fit:

Comment: please help me to solve this error

Comment: You're getting that error just by loading all those files, without actually writing custom code?

Comment: i wrote custom code for ui slider but i dont know why its throwing error.

Comment: So, what's your working hypothesis so far? That the bug is in someone else's code?

Comment: i am new in jquery. so i cant find out why its throwing error.

Comment: Libraries have bugs, but 99.99% of the times something doesn't work the problem is in your own code, esp. when you aren't proficient yet in that technology. Don't expect that someone will answer "yes, that's a known issue in jQuery, enable option foo and you'll be done". The problem is in your code. Seriously.

Comment: please tell me how can i know that my code is wrong, so atleast i solve that